# Inserting variable values into SQL Server using Java

Tags: java

So far I have been able to insert data into my SQL table only when i declare values inside the executedUpdate statement.  What I wanted to know if there is a way that I can pass those values as variables that I will declare as parameters in the executing method like so:

```
public void updateSQL(String name, String dnsName, String ipV4, String ipV6, int statusCode)
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://servername;database=databasename;integratedSecurity=true");

        System.out.println("Database Name: " + connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName());

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ComputerStatus(Name, DNSName, IPAddressV4, IPAddressV6, StatusCodeID)" + "VALUES(@Name, @DNSName, @IPAddressV4, @IPAddressV6, @StatusCodeID)");
        System.out.println("Data Inserted");

        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT Name FROM ComputerStatus");

        while(resultSet.next())
        {
            System.out.println("Computer Name: " + resultSet.getString("Name"));
        }

        connection.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Problem Connecting!");
    }
}
```

I've tried couple of different things but no luck so far.  Anyone know if this can be done?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement`.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("insert into test (firstname, lastname) values (?, ?");
stmt.setString(1, name);
stmt.setString(2, lname);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Using this way, you prevent SQL injection.

Comment: it should be `stmt.executeUpdate()` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look here :

```
PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ComputerStatus(Name, DNSName, IPAddressV4, IPAddressV6, StatusCodeID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
prep.setString(1, name);
prep.setString(2, dnsName);
prep.setString(3, ipV4name);
prep.setString(4, ipV6);
prep.setInt(5, statusCode);
prep.executeUpdate();
```

[this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) will help you understand.