# How to pass ? in SQL query for partial search

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I am fighting with a sql query for the past 1 day. My requirement is like I want to get the values from user and have to pass my query

```
select * from table1 where column1 like '%healt%'
```

But how to use the same query when we are passing the variable from client side or UI side?

I tried the query by using ?,@., like given below

```
select * from table where column like '%' ?'%'
```

but nothing worked. And nother issue I am facing with is using the OR operator.

When I am going with search criteria I want to display results by giving value to any one of the field. But in sql it is asking for all the columns which I am passing.

```
select * from table1 where column1 like ? OR cloumn2 like ?
```

But in the above SQL server is asking me to pass the value for both **column1** and **column2**. what changes I want to make to get results by passing any one of the column?

Kindly Help me in solving this issue.

Comment: Did you try just adding `+` on each side of your `?`?

Comment: ya. I have tried, but its not working.

`select * from table1 where column1 like '%'+?+'%'`

Comment: add `Java`-tag to your question, if you want code for `Java` as creating SqlQuery with parameters...

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where column like '%' + @variable +'%'
```

Also add the same variable as a parameter to the command in the code.

Comment: @variable?? you mean my colum name? and another thing, whether it can be applicable for string variables? because it should use string concatenation

Comment: No. I mean the value. "healt" in your example.
If you are using c#, then the SQLCommand object has a Parameters property.
Add a parameter with the value you seek.

Comment: what does this `@test`,`@variable` denotes? so how does this helps me to pass the value from clientside or from UI side?

Comment: What technology is used on the client side/UI side?

Here is an example of how to do it from C# :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056872/how-to-pass-variable-into-sqlcommand-statement-and-insert-into-database-table

Comment: clint side is java. so when i call this query through a java code, i have to use get() method and in the implementation layer I have to use set() method. so by using ? in the query, the get and set method can pass the value to the ? in the query. But i am failing in using partial search using LIKE keyword

Comment: Okay. Then try '%' + ? +'%'.

Comment: @bornas: thanks much for your reply. But the language that I use on front end is JAVA. Can you provide me for JAVA

Comment: From this article
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078744/inserting-variable-values-into-sql-server-using-java

It would look kinda like this :


PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("select * from table1 where column1 like '%' + ? + '%'");

Comment: The above select statement which you have given is not working. I am also trying the same with different possibilities, but everything is failing

Comment: Sorry. I don't even have a Java environment to test it.
You should add the Java tag to the question.

Comment: If you are working with DB2, you should remove the SQL Server tag and add a DB2 tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
  select * from table where where col1 like '%' + @test + '%'
```

Comment: what does this `@test`,`@variable` denotes? so how does this helps me to pass the value from clientside or from UI side?

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @yourParam1 varchar(20), @yourParam2 varchar(20)

set @yourParam1 = 'healt'
set @yourParam2 = 'abc'

select * from table where column1 like '%' + @yourParam + '%'
or column2 like '%' + @yourParam2 + '%'
```

my test is this.

my table

[image: My Table]

my Result

[image: My Result]

Procedure is like this

```
--exec Pr_Test 'healt' --this is your execute SQL

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pr_Test]
      @yourParam varchar(20),

AS
BEGIN
   select * from table where column like '%' + @yourParam + '%'    
END
```

in java like this

```
  String prName ="call "Pr_Test(?, ?)"
    .....
    cs.setString(1, "healt")
```

Comment: So everytime I cant set the `@param value`. It should be passed from the UI side or setvalue function. so when i call this query through a java code, i have to use `get()` method and in the implementation layer I have to use `set()` method. so by using ? in the query, the get and set method can pass the value to the ? in the query. But i am failing in using partial search using LIKE keyword

Comment: as of now if the get the set methods from java has to work. for that I have to pass ? in the query

Comment: I use "sql server management studio", it could be work with Procedure

Comment: But I am using DB2 server in which the server is configured directly in RAD, so that you can work with the tables form the datasource explorer view

Comment: could you give me a vote,thanks! you could find a UI for your DB2

Answer (score 0):

Use `SQL parameters` on Client/UI side:

in your C# or other code create a `SqlParameter` :

```
String searchValue = "test values";
// adding '&' signs
searchValue = String.Format("%{0}%", searchValue);

SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter("@YourParam", searchValue);
```

After this add this parameter to your `SqlCommand` object

Comment: :I am specific to java. think this might work on C#, but following similar kind of method in java wont help

Comment: Point of my answer is only add `'%' + yourValue + '%'` before creating a Parameter